# How to select distinct values (more than one value) in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have to make a query where I get the number of unique values from a database. In this database(type of jobs). In the column "jobs" there are strings like "doctor, lawyer" or "paramedic, banker, teacher". When I do the query:

SELECT DISTINCT jobs
FROM Type_Of_Jobs

I get some rows that only include **one** string, but I need combinations (so not just one value) and I need to be able to return # of those unique combinations. How do I do this in bigquery? Thank you!

Comment: In order to better clarify the question my suggestion is to include an example of how your data set is made and the desired result.

Comment: It's not really clear of want you want to expect. What is the "combination" that you want to count?

Comment: @Helen . . . I understand neither why your question would be downvoted nor why my answer would be.

Answer (score 1):

Use `split()` and `unnest()`:

```
select job, count(*)
from type_of_jobs tj cross join
     unnest(split(jobs, ',')) job
group by job;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a simple count for each combination of job string as it is or you want each combination to be split into the individual job and distinct count of the individual job?

For each combination of job string as it is:

```
SELECT jobs, count(*) count
FROM Type_Of_Jobs
group by jobs
```

For a distinct count of the individual job, look at Gordon's answer.